# Jquery appending list after localStorage JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This has been causing me a headache for the last hour. Basically I check localStorage to see if I have a cached version of a JSON string.  If I do, I load it up and convert it back to a JSON object.  If there is not a cached version, I use Ajax and grab the JSON object from the server.

Either way, after I have my JSON object, I call a parseDirectory function that iterates my JSON data and creates my html.  After parsing, it will append the HTML to my page. I have tested both methods and they both create my HTML successfully.. so I know my JSON data is good.  I loaded the cached version of the JSON data and ran it in JSONLint and it was valid.

The weird part is when I load the Cached JSON object, the jQuery append function doesn't work.  It *DOES* work when I download it using the Ajax call.  Here's the code

```
function loadPhoneList()

    //clearCache("Directory");

// Check if we have a cached version available

    if (isJSONCached("Directory")==true)
    {
        // We have a cached version of this module. Let's load that up
        var JSONobj = loadCachedJSON("Directory");
        parseDirectory(JSONobj);
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
            url: 'http://www.myserver.com/directory.php',
            data: 'cname=' + customername,
            success: function (data)
            {
                // Cache this new JSON info
                cacheJSON("Directory", data );

                // Parse the received JSON data
                parseDirectory(data);

            },
            error: function (errormsg)
            {
                alert(errormsg);
            }
        });
    }

    // Parse the JSON and create our content
    function parseDirectory(JSONobj)
    {
        var model_list = '';

        for (var i=0;i<JSONobj.directory_data.length;i++)
        {
            model_list += '<li class="item item-text-wrap"><p>' + JSONobj.directory_data[i].Name + '</p><p>' + JSONobj.directory_data[i].Number + '</p></li>';
        }

        alert(model_list);

        $("#directoryList").append(model_list);
    }
}
```

The HTML is

```
<div class="content-nopadding" >

    <div class="list">
        <div class="item item-divider">
            <center>Phone Directory</center>
        </div>

        <ul class="list" id="directoryList">
            <li class="filler"></li>
        </ul>

    </div>          

</div>
```

** EDIT.  Added the cacheJSON code **

```
// Used to store a cached version of a JSON string in localStorage by Key value
function cacheJSON( key, json )
{
    // Need to convert the JSON object to a string so we can store it
    var JSONtoStr = JSON.stringify(json);

    window.localStorage.setItem(key,JSONtoStr);
}
```

Comment: My gut tells me that `cacheJSON("Directory", data );` is failing to store object in cache properly so it works for ajax but not for cache, and if tested separately it looks ok.

Comment: Thanks for the reply LIUFA. In testing it both ways, parseDirectory creates proper HTML with both the cached JSON and AJAX json

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked great in JSFiddle.. Since I'm developing this on a mobile device, the reason was the DOM wasn't loaded prior to the JS being run.  I added a onDeviceReady event handler which solved the problem.

Thanks for looking!